# Proof that Bernoulli Distribution is Unmodified by Exponential Condition

Tags: conditional-probability, bernoulli-distribution

I have a probability density function as follows:

\begin{equation}
P_{X|T}(t, a, b) =
\begin{cases}
 \text{Bernoulli}(p = a(1 - e^{-\frac{-t}{b}}))  \text{ where } t\leq T \\ 0  \text{ otherwise} 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f_{T}(c) =  \text{Exp}(c) = \frac{e^{-\frac{t}{c}}}{c}
\end{equation}

It is trivial to show from the tower property ($E(X) = E(E(X|t))$) that:

\begin{equation}
 E(X; a, b, c) = \int^{T}_{0} P_{X|T}(t,a,b) \cdot f_{T}(c) = \int^{T}_{0} a(1 - e^{-\frac{-t}{b}})  \frac{e^{-\frac{t}{c}}}{c} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 E(X; a,b,c) = \frac{a}{b + c} \left(c - e^{-\frac{T}{c}}\left( c + b\cdot(1 - e^{-\frac{T}{b}}) \right) \right)
\end{equation}

I have noticed that then, this is equivalent to saying:

\begin{equation}
P_{X}(t, a, b, c) =  \text{Bernoulli}(E(X; a,b,c))
\end{equation}

Is there a trivial way that I can prove that this statement, or is it somehow implicit?

Comment: Unless you want $T=+\infty$, there is an issue in the normalisation of $f_t$, the denominator should be $1-e^{-T/c}$ rather than $c$

Comment: I think this point solved my problem. I have provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I mistakenly forgot an important feature that trivialises this problem:

\begin{equation}
P_{X|t}(t, a, b) =
\begin{cases}
 \text{Bernoulli}(p = a(1 - e^{-\frac{-t}{b}}))  \text{ where } t\leq T \\ 0  \text{ otherwise} 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The probability of a success is $E_{X}(t; a, b, c)$, as we have calculated. This follows from the Law of Total Probability:

\begin{equation}
P_{X}(a, b, c) = \int^{T}_{0} P_{X|T}(t, a, b) \cdot f_{t}(c).dt
\end{equation}

Equivalently, the probability of a failure must be:

\begin{equation}
P_{\overline{X}}(a, b, c) = \int^{T}_{0} (1 - P_{X|T}(t, a, b))\cdot f_{t}(c).dt + \int^{\infty}_{T} f_{t}(c).dt
\end{equation}

The second part of the expression arises from the fact that there is certain failure if $t>T$.

We integrate and obtain:
\begin{equation}
P_{\overline{X}}(a, b, c) = (1 - e^{-\frac{T}{c}}) - P_{X}(a, b, c) +  e^{-\frac{T}{c}}
\end{equation}

Which cancels to:
\begin{equation}
P_{\overline{X}}(a, b, c) = 1 - P_{X}(a, b, c)
\end{equation}

Since $X$ cannot take a value other than a success or a failure, we must conclude that:

\begin{equation}
X \sim P_{X}(a, b, c)^{s} + (1-P_{X}(a, b, c))^{1-s} \text{ where } s \in (0, 1)
\end{equation}

and that therefore:

\begin{equation}
X \sim \text{Bernoulli}(P_{X}(a, b, c))
\end{equation}